# jquery input on keypress not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some jquery script used to check password strength which changes an img src depending on complexity.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xh4g44sw/1/)

Which works well within jsfiddle (set to jquery 1.91 - I know I need to get it updated at some point, but don't have time to go over the entire site right now) - on my webpage however, the event isn't being fired.

even going for something more simple:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#txtNewPass').on('input', function () {
        alert('input');
    });
</script>
<input type="password" id="txtNewPass" runat="server" />
```

the alert doesn't popup.

I'm sure it is something silly I've overlooked, but I'd appreciate if someone could point it out.

Thanks

Comment: Your website is simply missing `$(document).ready`, which jsFiddle adds for you automagically.

Comment: As above: `$(function() { $('#txtNewPass').on('input', function () {
        alert('input');
    }); };` will do it

Comment: Thanks - that was certainly part of it.  But it was on my master page, so txtNewPass was actually coming up as ctl00_txtNewPass - so the event was never firing as the control id didn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
$(function () {
    $('#txtNewPass').on('keypress', function () {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You might be looking for keydown/keyup

```
$( "#target" ).keydown(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .keydown() called." );
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe the correct event you're looking for is 'change', not 'input'.

```
$('#txtNewPass').on('change', function () {
    alert('input');
});
```

You can also use

```
$('#txtNewPass').change()
```

https://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: well, no. input is a perfectly valid event.